# Creating a nested recursive list without slicing

Tags: python, list, recursion

I need to write a function that receives an non-negative integer and returns:

```
[] for n=0 

[[]] for n=1 

[[],[[]]] for n=2

[[],[[]],[[],[[]]]] for n=3
```

And so on. For `n`, we will receive an `n` sized list, so that in index `i` there will be all the `i-1` elements from the list. I don't know how to explain that better, English isn't my first language.

**I'm not allowed to use list slicing or loops** and I'm supposed to create deep copies of each list, without the `copy` module. I'm not allowed to let 2 different lists or indexes point to the same list in memory.

This is what I tried:

```
def list_seq(x, outer_list=[]):
    if x == 0:
        return []
    outer_list.append(list_seq(x-1,outer_list))
    return outer_list
```

And the output for `print(list_seq(2))` is `[[], [...]]`.

Comment: "I'm suppose to create deep copies of each list" Does that mean you are not supposed to cache the results of recursive calls? In this case, the will have _very_ high complexity.

Comment: @tobias_k I'm not allowed that 2 different lists or indexes will point on the same list in memory

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Do you consider the solution of your problem, created in C++?

Comment: @MadaBit why did you roll back your code attempt? The question would be off-topic without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't use loops, you can use the following:

```
def recursive_list(n):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    else:
        return recursive_list(n-1) +  [recursive_list(n-1)]
```

### EDIT

You can do the following if you want to use `append`:

```
def recursive_list(n: int) -> list:
    if n:
        result = recursive_list(n-1)
        result.append(recursive_list(n-1))
        return result
    return []
```

**NOTE** as pointed out in the comments, `caching` introduces some reference issues, so I have removed the cached versions.

Comment: That's a great solution. Thank you very much. Is it possible with append method instead of +? Maybe with an helper function

Comment: Added a solution with `append`.

Comment: Using `functools.cache` defeats the whole purpose of making two recursive calls instead of one. Consider: `l = recursive_list(4); print(l)`; 
`[[], [[]], [[], [[]]], [[], [[]], [[], [[]]]]]`; `l[1].append('oops'); print(l)`; `[[], [[], 'oops'], [[], [[], 'oops']], [[], [[], 'oops'], [[], [[], 'oops']]]]`

Comment: @Stef fair. I just made sure the lists are not self-contained. I did not consider whether  OP planned to append to the lists in-between, which is my oversight. Considering OP can't use slicing, or copy, or loops, not sure if the results can be cached at all. Even with some custom cache function, there needs to be some mechanism to copy the lists.

Answer (score 4):

You can write this down as a recursive function using a simple list comprehension:

```
def f(n):
    return [f(i) for i in range(n)]
```

Or instead of the list comprehension, you could also use `map`:

```
def f(n):
    return list(map(f, range(n)))
```

Note, though, that without [caching](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) this is going to get rather slow rather quickly.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to mention that i can't use loops

Comment: @MadaBit `return [*map(f, range(n))]` then?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative shorter recursive solution, no loops:

```
def l_list(n):
  def f(c, d = []):
     return d if c == n else f(c+1, d+[l_list(c)])
  return f(0)

print(l_list(0))
print(l_list(1))
print(l_list(2))
print(l_list(3))
```

Output:

```
[]
[[]]
[[], [[]]]
[[], [[]], [[], [[]]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another idea, I think it fulfills all rules/requirements:

```
def f(n):
    a = []
    exec('a.append(1 * a);' * n)
    return eval(repr(a))
```

Demo usage:

```
for n in range(5):
    print(f(n))
```

Output:

```
[]
[[]]
[[], [[]]]
[[], [[]], [[], [[]]]]
[[], [[]], [[], [[]]], [[], [[]], [[], [[]]]]]
```

Comment: Neat idea, but scary implementation. Why not just `for _ in range(n): a.append(list(a))` and then `return a`?

Comment: @tobias_k Because of the question's "**I'm not allowed to use list slicing or loops**".

Comment: @tobias_k And also because of its "I'm not allowed to let 2 different lists or indexes point to the same list in memory".

Comment: @tobias_k [It doesn't](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P1HBViE6listv0ghXiEzT6EoMS89VcNI04pLAQgS9RILClLzUjRyMotLNBI1NbkKijLzQCwYI9ogViGzWCEx2jAWyNT8/x8A)